# Error when trying to Set custom Object while looping through a Collection

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having some trouble with a collection of some custom class I created. It goes like this:
I've got my 'Client' Class Module containing necessary public fields. Then I have a custom 'Client' Collection containing information from my worksheets, 3000something items. Some of them are duplicates, because they might exist on multiple worksheets but I want the individual entries anyway because different worksheets contain different information. So for example; 
Client A in worksheet A, contains Name, Phone and Address and the same Client A in worksheet B, contains a 2nd Phone Number, amount of orders, and some additional info, so I want both entries in order not to miss any data. So my logic is by looping through this collection, I search for clients with the same FirstName and LastName and when there's a match I'm using a custom function to 'merge' these two listings together, only keeping non empty fields from each listing. But once I try to Set the current item to the new 'merged' one, I get 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error. Why is this happening? My code is below.

```
For j = 1 To clientCollection.Count
    For i = j + 1 To clientCollection.Count
        If clientCollection(j).lastName = clientCollection(i).lastName Then
            If clientCollection(j).firstName = clientCollection(i).firstName Then

                'The following line generates the error
                Set clientCollection(j) = Tools.MergeClients(clientCollection(j), clientCollection(i))
                clientCollection.Remove (i)
                duplicateCounter = duplicateCounter + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Below is my code for the MergeClients function:

```
Public Function MergeClients(clientA As Client, clientB As Client) As Client
    Dim testClient As Client
    Set testClient = New Client

    With testClient
        .email = IIf(Len(clientA.email) > 0, clientA.email, clientB.email)
        .fatherName = IIf(Len(clientA.fatherName) > 0, clientA.fatherName, clientB.fatherName)
        .firstName = IIf(Len(clientA.firstName) > 0, clientA.firstName, clientB.firstName)
        .information = IIf(Len(clientA.information) > 0, clientA.information, clientB.information)
        .lastName = IIf(Len(clientA.lastName) > 0, clientA.lastName, clientB.lastName)
        .phoneA = IIf(Len(clientA.phoneA) > 0, clientA.phoneA, clientB.phoneA)
        .phoneB = IIf(Len(clientA.phoneB) > 0, clientA.phoneB, clientB.phoneB)
    End With

    Set MergeClients = New Client
    Set MergeClients = testClient

End Function
```

To my understanding this seems like an error related to my 'Client' being a collection object because I have no issues setting a temporary new client to the mergeclient function, for example

```
dim tempClient as Client
set tempClient = new Client

set tempClient = Tools.MergeClients(clientA, clientB)

'But if I try the same thing but with the current collection object then it fails
set clientCollection(i) = Tools.MergeClients(clientA, clientB)
```

I tried describing my problem as best as I could, hope it's clear. I'd appreciate some insight on the matter! Thanks.

Comment: I assume the line `set tempClient as new Client` has a typo, right?

Comment: Can we see the definition of `clientCollection`? Is it just the built-in `VBA.Collection` or a custom object? Also, the `Set MergeClients = New Client` is unnecessary.

Comment: If  `clientCollection` was a normal `VBA.Collection` we would get a type mismatch error. But, of course, your remarks are absolutely valid.

Comment: And I also assume `Tools` is just the name of a module, right?

Comment: @Storax Yes it's a typo sorry, Set tempClient = new Client. and yes Tools is just another module containing a few functions.

The clientCollection is the generic VBA collection

Really my problem is at the specified line. Can I not directly set an object when I'm referencing it while looping through the collection?

Comment: Do you want `For j = 1 To clientCollection.Count - 1` rather than `For j = 1 To clientCollection.Count`?

Comment: @JohnColeman yes this seems to be correct but my code fails at the first iteration. Once I get the first match.

Comment: @KostasK. The point of my observation was about the interaction of that loop with the nested loop which immediately follows it, which starts at `j+1`

Comment: What is more, I noticed in my Watch window that my function returns data of type 'Object/Client' while my i'th collection object (which is a Client) is type of 'Variant/Object/Client' I don't know if this has something to do with it. I really never understood why there is this separation bewteen types in vba editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got now what you want to do. You want to change the object you stored in the collection.

You have to do it like that

```
Set tmpClient = Tools.MergeClients(clientA, clientB)
With clientCollection.Item(i)
    .eMail = tempClient.eMail
    .firstName = tempClient.firstName
    ' ... and so on
End With
```

Further reading [Are_Items_in_a_Collection_Read-Only](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#Are_Items_in_a_Collection_Read-Only)

Comment: Ah, this explains it then. Thank you for your time. I'll implement this somehow. Thanks again !